# Table with tcolorbox doesn't work correctly

Tags: color, tabularx, tcolorbox, colortbl

I define mytables using tcolorbox, but doesn't work.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\tcbuselibrary{listings,skins,theorems,xparse,fitting}


\newtcolorbox{mytables}{%
width=\linewidth,
enhanced,
fonttitle=\bfseries\large,
fontupper=\normalsize\sffamily,
colback=yellow!10!white,
colframe=red!50!black,
colbacktitle=green,
coltitle=black,
center title}

\begin{document}

\begin{mytables}[tabularx={|X|},title=My table]
  a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z \\\hline
  A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z \\\hline
  0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
\end{mytables}


\end{document}
```

output:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax of `\newtcolorbox` is as follows:

```
\newtcolorbox[⟨init options⟩]{⟨name⟩}[⟨number⟩][⟨default⟩]{⟨options⟩}
```

with `[⟨number⟩]` being the number of arguments the new environment is supposed to have and `[⟨default⟩]` being the default value of the first argument. Since you did not include `[1][]` in your code, the first argument was not expected resultin in an error message. In order to not only tell `tcolorbox` that `mytables` is expecting an optional argument, but in order to also use whatever code you add there, I also added `#1` in the definition of the `mytables` environment.

I also added an alternaitve in which I used `\tcbset`and defined a new style that can be used with the regular `tcolorbox` environment. Both approaches result in the following output:

[image]

Some minor comments on the packages in the preamble: The use of `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` already loads `colortbl`, so no need for `\usepackage{colortbl}`. Similarly, `tabularx` loads `array`, so no need to explicitly load the latter. Lastly, `amssymb` internally loads `amsfonts`, so you can omit the latter.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings,skins,theorems,xparse,fitting}



\newtcolorbox{mytables}
[1][]                        % <----------- added
{% 
width=\linewidth,
enhanced,
fonttitle=\bfseries\large,
fontupper=\normalsize\sffamily,
colback=yellow!10!white,
colframe=red!50!black,
colbacktitle=green,
coltitle=black,
center title, 
#1                            %<------------- added
}

\tcbset{mytables/.style={%
width=\linewidth,
enhanced,
fonttitle=\bfseries\large,
fontupper=\normalsize\sffamily,
colback=yellow!10!white,
colframe=red!50!black,
colbacktitle=green,
coltitle=black,
center title}}

\begin{document}

\begin{mytables}[tabularx={|X|},title=My table]
  a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z \\\hline
  A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z \\\hline
  0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
\end{mytables}


\begin{tcolorbox}[mytables,tabularx={|X|},title=My table]
  a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z \\\hline
  A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z \\\hline
  0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```